# What can I do when avoiding overdrawing conflicted with batch rendering in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, render

Say, I have some render units sorted in distance from camera order.

Such as `ru0, ru1, ru2, ru3, ru4, ru5...`.The purpose of doing this is to avoid overdrawing by z depth test.

But, in batch rendering view, this is a kind of wast.

Assume, `ru1, ru3, ru5` have same render state(same opengl state, and same shader program), So they should be batched and render in one time.

But, this is not Avoiding overdrawing want me to do.

So, my question is, is this a problem based on specific scenario(such as in some case, the overdrawing's consuming time is not more than opengl state changing's consuming) or there is another way to solve this problem?

**NOTE, all my render units are opaque, so I am not taking transparent unit into account here.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern hardware is very likely to implement ["Early z-test"](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test), i.e. performing depth test before fragment (pixel) shader is run. Alternatively, it is implementable by hand.

So, it is likely more beneficial to sort by state,  unless you have transparency issues. In the latter case you may want to look into ["Order-independent transparency"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency).

In any case, trust no one. Measure (profile) and compare before optimizing anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you meaning this is a problem which may have different answer in different case ?@Drop

Comment: @francis Yes, as basically any problem in this universe.